# What are "minuhome.Black.[...]" apps?

Tags: security

I've downloaded an app locker on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8, and as I was trying to import apps to the locker, on category "M" of the app list comes out a lot of Android icons with the file name of `minuhome.Black.[...]`.

[image]

What are these apps? Am I being hacked?

Comment: Based on [googling "minuhome"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=minuhome), looks like it's Samsung Galaxy's launcher/theme app.

Answer (score 1):

Minu is one of the themers who makes Samsung themes. Those are all the overlays for every package that the theme themes. If you want to removee them you'll have to remove the theme, but they're all small and they don't contain any code at all, just resources (XMLs, PNGs, voctors, etc.)